# firebase authentication with Laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication to authenticate users with Laravel,

```
$firebase_id_token =  Cookie::get('idtoken');

$verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($firebase_id_token);
```

and I am getting InvalidArgumentException Error :
"It was not possible to parse your key, reason: "

on the verifyIdToken, although $firebase_id_token is valid,

I am using Laravel Homestead
PHP 8.0.3
"firebase": "^7.24.0",
"firebaseui": "^4.6.1",

Comment: Is your Cookie set by JS? If so, it might be in plain text and if you don't have an exception set for it, Laravel will try to decrypt it, thus ending with an invalid token.

Comment: Yes VueJS, I am totally new to this, what should I do if this is the case?

Comment: here is my code   -------------------                                                                                                      
          try {
            $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($firebase_id_token);
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
            
        } catch (InvalidToken $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());  
        }

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie is set by JS, it will probably be stored as plain text (unless you encrypt it).

If that's the case, in your `app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php` middleware add an exception for the cookie:

```
protected $except = [
    'idtoken'
];
```

Comment: thank you, dear, yes it is set by JS, but I've already added this exception but didn't work! thanks

Comment: Then probably there is a something wrong in `Auth::verifyIdToken`. Did you check if the value set by JS matches the one passed to `Cookie::get('idtoken')`?

Comment: that's true, they are not the same!!! any idea what should I do?

Comment: I have one word for you: debug :D. Start by checking the value of the token before is set by Vue and the value after is set. If they differ, probably Vue is encrypting it.